# Вылетают сессии после оплаты на странице банка

Tags: php, yii, сессия

Пользователь заходит на сайт платного тестирования, авторизуется, формируется заказ и пользователю выставляется счет, после чего пользователь переходит на платежную страницу обслуживающего нас банка для оплаты картой.

**Проблема:** После того как оплата успешно проведена, пользователь нажимает кнопку на странице банка "Вернуться на сайт", а именно:

```
<input type="button" onclick="location.href="http://www.mysite.com/test"" value="Вернуться на сайт">
```

Однако вместо того чтобы попасть на страницу тестирования пользователь вновь попадает на страницу авторизации, так как сессия, содержащая данные пользователя вылетела. Примечательно то, что уже авторизовавшись в этот раз и последующие разы все работает нормально. Но стоит нажать "Выйти" на сайте и попытаться пройти тестирование вновь, проблема появляется.

Сайт сделан на Yii. Вот код UserIdentity:

```
class UserIdentity extends CUserIdentity
{

    private $_id;

    public function authenticate()
    {

        $user=User::model()->findByAttributes(array('name'=>$this->username));
        if($user===null){
            $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID;
        }
        else if(!$user->validatePassword($this->password)){
            $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID;
        }
        else
        {
            $this->_id=$user->id;
            $this->username=$user->name;
            if(!empty($user->role))
                $this->setState('role', $user->role);
            $this->setState('confirmed', $user->confirmed);
            $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_NONE;
        }
        return $this->errorCode==self::ERROR_NONE;
    }

   public function getId()
    {
        return $this->_id;
    }
}
```

Пробовал сохранить обычную сессию типа $_SESSION[""], но она тоже обнуляется после возврата с банка на сайт.

Битый час потратил на решение этой проблемы. В чем может быть дело? Может кто-то с этим сталкивался? Как её решить?
Если какого-то кода не хватает дайте знать.

Спасибо.

Comment: `Yii::app()->user->login($identity, $time);`  
Возможно, придется еще подергать [настройки сессии](http://www.larryullman.com/2011/05/03/using-sessions-with-the-yii-framework/)

Comment: у меня стоит стандартный код:

<code>
$duration=$this->rememberMe ? 3600*24*30 : 0; // 30 days
   Yii::app()->user->login($this->_identity,$duration);
</code>

Comment: @z_coder, вышенаписанное в общем-то стремится не решить проблему, а отключить все возможности автоматического управления сессией, чтобы она не грохнулась. Все это выглядит довольно странно, но такое бывает и проще проигнорировать и обойти, чем искать корень. Тем не менее, $duration при тестах 0 или 30 дней? И в момент нахождения на странице банка куки сессии присутствуют?

Comment: > отключить все возможности автоматического управления сессией, чтобы она не грохнулась
Что здесь конкретно имели ввиду?
>И в момент нахождения на странице банка куки сессии присутствуют?
Как проверить?

Comment: @z_coder, [стандартный синтаксис Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax), строка в обратных апострофах (\`code\`) - строчное (инлайновое) форматирование кода, параграф, с индентом в четыре пробела или заключенный в тройные обратные апострофы - многострочный код.

Comment: @z_coder > Что здесь конкретно имели ввиду?

Форсировать [использование cookie](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/ru/topics.auth#sec-4) в Yii и посмотреть, не исчезнет ли проблема. С setState после этого надо будет поосторожней, конечно. Я бы вообще слез с движка сессий пыха и использовал CDbSession.

> Как проверить?

После перехода в банк зайти на сайт (не производя никаких действий в банке) и проверить авторизацию (и заодно посмотреть, менялся ли PHPSESSID в куках)

Comment: >Форсировать использование cookie в Yii и посмотреть, не исчезнет ли проблема

Поясните пожалуйста, что вы здесь имели ввиду.